# Stencil and SVG attribute xlink-href

Tags: svg, stenciljs

With Stencil 1.8.0 this code worked:

```
<svg>
  <use xlinkHref="#some-icon"/>
</svg>
```

recently Stencil was updated to 1.11 and the mentioned code stopped working. When I tryed to built the project I got Typescript error, saying:

```
Type '{ xlinkHref: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SVGAttributes<SVGElement>'.
Property 'xlinkHref' does not exist on type 'SVGAttributes<SVGElement>'.
```

I searched around and found out that `xlinkHref` was renamed into `xlink-href` [(link)](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/commit/667597dd1aebf05aae171a4cfcba2baad59b50b8)

If I change the code to:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink-href="#some-icon"/>
</svg>
```

the build process passes without errors, but then in the browser's console I get:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on 'Element': The qualified name 
provided ('-href') contains the invalid name-start character '-'.
    at setAccessor (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:618:25)
    at updateElement (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:646:9)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:695:13)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
    at createElm (http://localhost:3334/build/index-a8bdf364.js:705:29)
```

I didn't find any examples or documentation on this.

Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer thanks to Max from Stencil chat on Slack. It's a temporary fix while the fix is in the workings.

```
import { JSXBase } from '@stencil/core/internal';

    // render()
    type SVG2Attributes = JSXBase.SVGAttributes & { href: string };

    // @ts-ignore
    const link = <use href="example" /> as SVG2Attributes;

    return (
      <svg>
        {link}
      </svg>
    );
```

Comment: could you make a link to the stencil issue? thanks!